# How to validate dateField in django form

Tags: python, django, datetime

I am trying to validate my Date of birth field in my Django form. I want the d_o_b field to be less than the current year.

```
def validate_dob(value):
    # fxn that check if date of birth is not the current year
    if value >  datetime.date.year():
        raise forms.ValidationError('Date must be greater than current year')
```

I get the below error when the try to execute the  above code:

`TypeError at /account/edit/ 'getset_descriptor' object is not callable`

Here is my form:

```
class ProfileEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    dob = forms.DateField(validators = [validate_dob])
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('dob', 'photo')
        labels = {
                'dob': ('Date of birth'),
            }
        widgets = {
                'dob': DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'})
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

*year* attribute of a *datetime.date* field is not a callable.

def validate_dob(value):
if value >  datetime.date.year:
raise forms.ValidationError('...)